# BindingAdapter deprecation warnings

Tags: android, android-databinding

I use a BindingAdapter to implement validation for TextInputLayout fields. My object has an ObservableBoolean 'valid' that when changed will execute my binding adapter to set/clear the error message on the field. It works great but I now see the following warning and hoped to address it:

> Warning: Use of ObservableField and primitive cousins directly as
>   method parameters is deprecated and support will be removed soon. Use
>   the contents as parameters instead in method BindingUtils.setError

The adapter:

```
@BindingAdapter({"error", "errorMsg"})
public static void setError(TextInputLayout view, ObservableBoolean isValid, String errorMsg){
    String errorString = isValid.get() ? null : errorMsg;
    view.setError(errorString);
}
```

And the binding expression:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        app:error="@{viewModel.name.valid}"
        app:errorMsg="@{@string/template_details_error_name_required}"
```

To address the issue, I modified the adapter and binding expression as follows but this resulted in a new deprecation warning:

> Warning: Do not explicitly call 'get()' on ObservasbleFields in an
>   expression. This support will be removed soon.
>   'viewModel.name.valid.get()'

Modified adapter:

```
@BindingAdapter({"error", "errorMsg"})
public static void setError(TextInputLayout view, Boolean isValid, String errorMsg){
```

Modified binding expression:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    app:error="@{viewModel.name.valid.get()}"
    app:errorMsg="@{@string/template_details_error_name_required}"
```

What is the recommended way to acheive this now?

This related thread 
[Android Databinding BindingAdapter Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43806390/android-databinding-bindingadapter-error)
questions whether there is a valid use case for Observables in BindingAdapters. Perhaps this is one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're only supposed to change the adapter itself. `ObservableBoolean` is unwrapped automatically within the layout.

```
@BindingAdapter({"error", "errorMsg"})
public static void setError(TextInputLayout view, boolean isValid, String errorMsg){
    String errorString = isValid ? null : errorMsg;
    view.setError(errorString);
}
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    app:error="@{viewModel.name.valid}"
    app:errorMsg="@{@string/template_details_error_name_required}"
```

But your attribute name and parameter name don't match to well semantically.

Comment: Thank for explaining that types are unwrapped for you. Works perfectly now.